# Imprimir ticket en Crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, imprimir

recurro a ustedes abusando de su sabiduría para que nuevamente me orienten; estoy trabajando con c# y crystal reports todo bien hasta el momento de imprimir el ticket, ya que crystal reports no lo muestra en una sola pagina si no que lo fracciona en dos, y no se si es que hay alguna configuracion que desconozca o algo este haciendo mal[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto imagen representativa.

Answer (score 1):

Lamento que la respuesta sea tan tarde.
Te cuento, lo primero que debes hacer es verificar la configuracion de tu diseño en crystal reports debido a que el error que presentas se da cuando tienes mal configuradas las secciones dentro de tu reporte. Es decir algunas secciones que no utilizas pero las tienes disponibles para imprimir, procura configurarlas como"No profundizar" en el caso de que no quieres que se imprima.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual forma elimina las secciones que no estes utiliando puesto que pueden hacer que aumente el tamaño de tu pagina de impresión.
Espero te sirva. O alguien mas que pueda tener este inconveniente.